# Как расположить два контейнера по высоте на одном уровне

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование, table

У меня есть главный контейнер, в котором находятся ещё два контейнера (один с списком ul, а второй с таблицей, и у меня не выходит выровнять их верхние границы на одном уровне, пробовал играть со свойствами display: flex, inline-block, и тд, но не вышло, можете подсказать как мне выровнять их на одном уровне?

HTML

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="nav__second">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="/admins/adminsite/index.html">Создание товара</a></li>
                <hr style="margin-left: -16%; width: 274px;">
                <li><a href="#">Создание категории</a></li>
                <hr style="margin-left: -16%; width: 274px;">
                <li><a href="#">Создание подкатегории</a></li>
                <hr style="margin-left: -16%; width: 274px;">
                <li><a href="#">Настройка товара</a></li>
                <hr style="margin-left: -16%; width: 274px;">
                <li><a href="#">Настройка категории</a></li>
                <hr style="margin-left: -16%; width: 274px;">
                <li><a href="#">Настройка подкатегории</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div id="createtovar" class="create" >
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th colspan="2" style="text-align: center; background-color: #008faf;"><input
                            style="width: 98%; height: 30px; text-align: center;" type="text"
                            placeholder="Название товара.">
                    </th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Стоимость: <input style="width: 70%; height: 30px;" type="text" placeholder="₽"></th>
                    <th>Единица измерения товара:
                        <select class="unit">
                            <option value="option0"></option>
                            <option value="option1">шт</option>
                            <option value="option2">кг</option>
                            <option value="option3">т</option>
                            <option value="option4">л</option>
                            <option value="option5">коробка</option>
                        </select>
                    </th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Изображение товара:</th>
                    <th><button style="width: 100%; height: 30px; background-color: #008faf; color: #fff;">Загрузить
                            изображение с
                            устройства</button></th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Описание товара:</th>
                    <th><textarea name="opisanie" style="width: 98.5%;" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea></th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Характеристики товара:</th>
                    <th><textarea name="haracteristika" style="width: 98.5%;" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea></th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Категория товара:</th>
                    <th>
                        <select>
                            <option>Выберите категорию</option>
                            <option>Категория 1</option>
                            <option>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Подкатегории</option>
                            <option>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Подкатегория 1</option>
                            <option>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Подкатегория 2</option>
                            <option>Категория 2</option>
                            <option>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Подкатегории</option>
                            <option>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Подкатегория 1.2</option>
                            <option>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Подкатегория 2.1</option>
                        </select>
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <button class="create-btn">Создать</button>
        </div>
```

CSS свойства относящиеся к HTML коду:

```
.container {
    display: flex;
    width: 80%;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: flex-start;
    margin-top: 5%;
}

.nav__second {
    max-width: 280px;
    margin-bottom: auto;
}

.nav__second ul {
    list-style: none;
    background-color: #008faf;
}

.nav__second li {
    padding: 4% 4%;
}

.nav__second a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.create {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для многих элементов, у браузеров есть стили по умолчанию. Конкретно в вашем случае, список имеет внешние отступы, поэтому ему достаточно прописать свойство `margin: 0` и проблема решится:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 80%;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
  margin-top: 5%;
}

.nav__second {
  max-width: 280px;
  margin-bottom: auto;
}

.nav__second ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #008faf;
}

.nav__second li {
  padding: 4% 4%;
}

.nav__second a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.create {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: auto;
}

.create table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="nav__second">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="/admins/adminsite/index.html">Создание товара</a></li>
      <hr style="margin-left: -16%; width: 274px;">
      <li><a href="#">Создание категории</a></li>
      <hr style="margin-left: -16%; width: 274px;">
      <li><a href="#">Создание подкатегории</a></li>
      <hr style="margin-left: -16%; width: 274px;">
      <li><a href="#">Настройка товара</a></li>
      <hr style="margin-left: -16%; width: 274px;">
      <li><a href="#">Настройка категории</a></li>
      <hr style="margin-left: -16%; width: 274px;">
      <li><a href="#">Настройка подкатегории</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div id="createtovar" class="create">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th colspan="2" style="text-align: center; background-color: #008faf;"><input style="width: 98%; height: 30px; text-align: center;" type="text" placeholder="Название товара.">
        </th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Стоимость: <input style="width: 70%; height: 30px;" type="text" placeholder="₽"></th>
        <th>Единица измерения товара:
          <select class="unit">
            <option value="option0"></option>
            <option value="option1">шт</option>
            <option value="option2">кг</option>
            <option value="option3">т</option>
            <option value="option4">л</option>
            <option value="option5">коробка</option>
          </select>
        </th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Изображение товара:</th>
        <th><button style="width: 100%; height: 30px; background-color: #008faf; color: #fff;">Загрузить
                            изображение с
                            устройства</button></th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Описание товара:</th>
        <th><textarea name="opisanie" style="width: 98.5%;" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea></th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Характеристики товара:</th>
        <th><textarea name="haracteristika" style="width: 98.5%;" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea></th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Категория товара:</th>
        <th>
          <select>
            <option>Выберите категорию</option>
            <option>Категория 1</option>
            <option>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Подкатегории</option>
            <option>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Подкатегория 1</option>
            <option>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Подкатегория 2</option>
            <option>Категория 2</option>
            <option>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Подкатегории</option>
            <option>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Подкатегория 1.2</option>
            <option>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Подкатегория 2.1</option>
          </select>
        </th>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <button class="create-btn">Создать</button>
  </div>
```

Comment: Хоть и по высоте есть разница в пару пискелей, но всё равно большое спасибо, смогли приблизить меня к эталонному виду, который хотелось видеть!

Comment: @PaLbl4 пара пикселей - это та же причина - у таблицы тоже есть дефолт. Дополнил ответ.